# Уникальные 3начение при генерации элементов массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, случайные-числа

Есть массив с 54 картами рандомом получаю 9 3начений, но периодический они повторяются, поискал темы чтобы исключить повторяющиеся числа ,но в таком случае он оставляет пустое 3начение в массиве а не 3аполнят его новым числом.

```
//3апись 9 id в массив randId
    var randId = new Array(9);
    for (var i = 0; i < randId.length; i++) { // В таблице 9 строк
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);
            if (randId.indexOf(rand) === -1) {         // проверим есть оно  у нас или нет
                randId[i] = rand;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const cards = ['♠A', '♠2', '♠3', '♠4', '♠5', '♠6', '♠7', '♠8', '♠9', '♠10', '♠J', '♠Q', '♠K',
  '♥A', '♥2', '♥3', '♥4', '♥5', '♥6', '♥7', '♥8', '♥9', '♥10', '♥J', '♥Q', '♥K',
  '♦A', '♦2', '♦3', '♦4', '♦5', '♦6', '♦7', '♦8', '♦9', '♦10', '♦J', '♦Q', '♦K',
  '♣A', '♣2', '♣3', '♣4', '♣5', '♣6', '♣7', '♣8', '♣9', '♣10', '♣J', '♣Q', '♣K', 'Joker', 'Joker'
];

let result = cards.map(card => {
  return {
    c: card,
    sort: Math.random()
  }
}).sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort).slice(0, 9).map(a => a.c);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: Забавный подход к задаче! (1 строка) Но Джокеров у нас два. Ваше решение хорошее, но т.к. `cards[52]==cards[53]`, его можно улучшить. Например, поставить "Red Jocker" и "Black Jocker"

Comment: А я давно не держал в руках карты, поэтому не помню, отличаются ли там друг от друга джокеры. :) Ну и вообще, была мысль генерировать этот массив программно, но поленился :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var cardsLength = 54; // instead of cards.length
var randIds = new Array(9);
for (var i = 0; i < randIds.length; i++) { // В таблице 9 строк
  var used = true;
  var randomIndex;
  while (used) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * cardsLength);
    used = randIds.indexOf(randomIndex) != -1;
  }
  randIds[i] = randomIndex;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(randIds));
```

Comment: Спасибо) бесконечные циклыы и выйти и3 него только при наличии элемента)

Answer (score 1):

Еще один вариант

```js
            var cardsLength = 54; // instead of cards.length
            var randIds = new Array(9);
            var cards = new Array(54); // здесь храним карты
            // Заполняем массив из 54 карт, которые затем будем "вытягивать", их "значениями" от 1 до 54
            for (var j = 0; j < 54; j++) cards[j] = j + 1;
            // 
            for (var i = 0; i < randIds.length; i++) { // В таблице 9 строк
                var cardIndex;  // индекс карты в оставшейся колоде
                var randomIndex;  // номер карты от 1 до 54
                // на каждом цикле объем выборки уменьшается (cardsLength - i)
                // получаем индекс карты из оставшихся в колоде
                cardIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cardsLength - i));
                // получаем номер карты
                randomIndex = cards[cardIndex];
                // добавляем номер карты в выходной массив
                randIds[i] = randomIndex;
                // удаляем карту из колоды
                cards.splice(cardIndex, 1);
            }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(randIds));
```